# Fontawesome Icons showing on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: .net-core, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, .net-core-3.1

My fontawesome icons are showing up in my select list on the desktop version of my app in Chrome, but on my mobile version (Galaxy S7) I get boxes, weird symbols and the occasional Japanese characters. I've read about 30 articles that say to set the font-weight to 900, but of course that doesn't help.

It seems the fonts are missing? But why does it work on the desktop version but not on mobile? I'm using fontawesome 5.5.0 and the cloudfare CDN. And I'm running .net core 3.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.5.0/css/all.min.css' rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="text-info border-0 fa fa-select fa-2x " id="Icon" name="Icon"><option class="fa-select" value="@Model.Icons[i].Id">@Html.Raw(Model.Icons[i].UnicodeWithHTML)</option></select>
```

Here's my css.

.fa-select {
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid';
font-weight: 400;
}

Comment: Q: Is the "desktop version" a C# ASP.Net Core app, with Razor pages, that you're displaying in a Chrome browser?  What exactly is the "mobile version"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using this bootstrap template - https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/angle-bootstrap-admin-template-WB04HF123

Comment: And yes,  it's a C# ASP.Net Core app, with Razor pages... using the bootstrap template above.

Answer (score 2):

So what I discovered is that android and IOS popovers apparently don't support the @font-family css, therefore can't display fontawesome icons correctly in the popover. Ultimately I ended up using a bootstrap button to toggle a panel with the items for selection, thereby keeping it all within the HTML portion of the browser.

Comment: Silly question: I've only ever created a .Net Core web app in Visual Studio, deployed it to IIS, and displayed it in a web browser (e.g. Chrome) on my Windows desktop.  Q: Did you build your app "differently" for mobile, or is it just a plain old .Net Core web app deployed to a web server?  Q: Are you displaying by browsing to a URL with Firefox or Chrome (Android) or Safari (IOS)?  Or did you deploy some kind of "mobile client" to your handset? You *didn't* create a separate, Xamarin or Power BI app, did you?  I'm curious...